# i want to convert my string code into PDF through asp.net-mvc controller using passing string through ajax call in controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to convert `HTML` string to `PDF` using `iron PDF` in `asp.net-mvc`. 
But that is trial version, so can you give me any other solution for this quotation to convert `HTML` string to `PDF` in `asp.net-MVC`.

Answer (score 0):

You upload file with input

```
 <input type="file" name="fileToController"/>
```

In Controller u can access it by doing

```
Request.Params["fileToController"] //ur uploaded file
```

Comment: no,i want to convert html   string to PDF using mvc controller, and i am passing string through ajax call.